# How to solve this system to model a simple betting system?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

What I am asking is just for my personal curiosity.

I was thinking about the betting system (ex. football). For example let's consider just this possibilities to bet:

```
Win of Team A      Draw      Win of Team B
2,0                4,0       8,0
```

As you know, if you bet 10€ on Win of Team A, and it wins, you get 20€ back.

I was wondering if you could bet on all three possibilities (with the right distribution of money) and be sure to get a reward > 0€. My common sense said "Of course not", otherwise everyone could always win.

I don't have a lot of Math knowledge, but I tried to formalize the problem to see why, analitically, it is impossible to do so.

Here is my attempt, but I can't go no further:

```
Win of Team A multiplier: a (constant)
Draw multiplier: d (constant)
Win of Team B: b (constant)

Money to bet on Win of Team A: x (variable)
Money to bet on Draw: y (variable)
Money to bet on Win of Team B: z (variable)
```

The system I want to solve (Is it the right way to express "Always win betting onto the all three?")

$$\begin{cases} ax -(x + y + z) > 0 \\ dy - (x + y + z) > 0 \\ bz - (x + y + z)> 0 \\ x \neq 0 \\ y \neq 0 \\ z \neq 0 \end{cases}$$

This system (to me) means: if you bet for the Win of Team A and you betted for the Others, you get all your betted money back plus something won... (the same for Draw and Win of Team B).

Then:

$$\begin{cases} ax > (x + y + z) \\ dy > (x + y + z) \\ bz > (x + y + z) \\ x \neq 0 \\ y \neq 0 \\ z \neq 0 \end{cases}$$

And:

$$\begin{cases} \frac{y+z}{x} > a-1 \\ \frac {x+z}{y} > d-1 \\ \frac {x+y}{z} > b-1 \\ \end{cases}$$

At this point I know that my knowledge of math is finished. I tried to trasform the system but I really can't solve it. I never studied disequations with 3 variables (nor 2, sigh). How can i solve it and verify for which values of x, y, z it is solvable?

Comment: *model* is already a verb. `:-P`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have $n$ mutually exclusive outcomes with payoffs $p_1, \ldots, p_n$.  (In your case $n=3$ and $p_1=2$, $p_2=4$, and $p_3=8$.)  I'll show that you can "game the system" to always win precisely when
$$S=\frac1{p_1}+\frac1{p_2}+\cdots+\frac1{p_n}<1.$$
This holds in your case, as $1/2+1/4+1/8<1$; the argument below shows how to place your bets and compute your guaranteed profit.

Assume you're going to distribute a bet $B$ over the $n$ outcomes, and assume an adversary is going to control the outcome *after* you place your bet.  Thus you want to maximize (over all distributions of the bet) the minimum payoff (over all $n$ possible outcomes).  We'll show that in the optimal strategy, the bet on outcome $i$ is proportional to $1/p_i$.  (More precisely, the bet on outcome $i$ is $B/(S p_i)$, so that the sum of the bets is $B$.)

If the outcome is $i$, your gross payoff is $p_i\cdot B/(S p_i)=B/S$ which is actually independent of $i$.  Since you've paid $B$ to play, your profit is guaranteed to be
$B/S - B$, which is positive exactly when $1/S-1>0$, i.e. when $S<1$.

Let's see why this is true.  Finding the optimal strategy is a linear programming problem, and you can do it with matrices and all that, but it's really easier.  Concentrate on outcomes $i$ and $j$; suppose you've bet $x_i$ and $x_j$ on those outcomes.  Your payoff for that investment of $x_i+x_j$ will be
$$\min (x_i p_i, x_j p_j).$$  The maximum of this payoff, subject to $x_i+x_j$ being fixed, occurs when $x_i p_i=x_j p_j$.  Therefore, no matter what your investment in other outcomes, if you haven't chosen $x_i:x_j$ in proportion to $1/p_i:1/p_j$, you can improve your payoff.  Since $i$ and $j$ are arbitrary, the optimal strategy must set $x_i$ proportional to $1/p_i$; thus
$$x_i=\frac B{p_i S}$$
so that the sum of the bets is $B$.

In your specific case, $1/S=1/(1/2+1/4+1/8)=8/7$, so your profit will be $B/7$ if you place a total bet $B$.  For example, if you bet $4$, $2$, and $1$ respectively, where the payoffs are $2$, $4$ and $8$ respectively, your total bet is $7$, and you're guaranteed to win $8$.

Comment: Thanks! Can you please give an explaination For the first relation you written?

Comment: The rest of the post is intended to explain that.  I'll see if I can clarify a little.

Comment: Sorry - the original post was **completely** wrong!  I should have noticed this.  It's correct now.

Comment: What was wrong? I don't see any edit to hour post :)

Comment: It's fixed now - my connection went out and the edit didn't actually post.